# Reverse geocoding on marker click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I have an embedded Google map with my web application in ASP.NET 3.5.

I have implemented reverse geocoding (getting address from latitude and longitude) on Map click.

Now, I need the same but on marker click.

How should I code marker click?

Answer (score 1):

For each of your markers, add the following event handler for the click event.  This assumes you're using the version 2 API.

```
// pass in a reference to your marker object and 
// bind the function to the click event
GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {        
    // perform your geocoding here
});
```

You can grab the coordinates of the marker with its `getLatLng()` method, which returns a [`GLatLng` object](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GLatLng).

More info can be found [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/events.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a call to your reverse-geocode function within the event listener for the marker's OnClick event.

`google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { infowindow.open(map,marker); });` Is a normal thing you might do to have the infowindow open when you click a marker.  Add another function() to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use de event **dragend**.

```
GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {        
    // perform your geocoding here
});
```

It just works :D